# Inverting a $2 \times 2$ matrix $\mod 26$

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am trying to invert the matrix (in mod 26)

\begin{bmatrix}
     19 & 7\\
    19 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}

I compute the determinant 
((19*0)-(19*7)=23 (Reducing in mod 26)

\begin{bmatrix}
     0 & -7\\
    -19 & 19 \\
\end{bmatrix}
Switch a & d and negate b & c

Multiply by 23^-1 = 17
To get

\begin{bmatrix}
     0 & 11\\
    15 & 25 \\
\end{bmatrix}

But this can't be right
since wolfram gives me

\begin{bmatrix}
     0 & 15\\
    11 & 11\\
\end{bmatrix}

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Use `$\times$` for $\times$.

Comment: The last matrix is not the correct inverse, do you mean $$\pmatrix{0&11\\15&11}$$ ?

Comment: Your approach was absolutely fine, but you made one miscalculation (See my answer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You miscalculated one entry : $$19\cdot 17\equiv 11\mod 26$$ giving the correct inverse

Comment: its -7 though, thats why Im confused 17*-7 mod 26 = -15 which is congurent to 11

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ be the given matrix. Then $AA^{-1}=I_2$. Hence, we must row reduce the augmented system:
$$\begin{bmatrix}19&7&|&1&0\\19&0&|&0&1\end{bmatrix}\to\begin{bmatrix}19&7&|&1&0\\0&-7&|&-1&1\end{bmatrix}\to \begin{bmatrix}19&0&|&0&1\\0&-7&|&-1&1\end{bmatrix}\to\begin{bmatrix}1&0&|&0&11\\0&1&|&-11&11\end{bmatrix}$$
using $19^{-1}=11$ and $-7=19$ in $\Bbb Z_{26}$.

Hence, $$A^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}0&11\\-11&11\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0&11\\15&11\end{bmatrix}\qquad\text{in $\Bbb Z_{26}$ since $-11=15$}$$

Comment: Nice calculation, but you didn't spot what the author of the question made wrong.

Comment: An even simpler calculation can be done by first noting $7 \equiv -19$, and so $A = 19 B$ with $B$ a simple $\{-1,0,1\}$ matrix with determinant $1$. So the inverse of $B$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{26}$ is the same as its inverse over $\mathbb{R}$, and we just need to multiply with the inverse of $19$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{26}$.